# NoMethodError in StatesController#create for undefined method `update_column'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Using Rails 3.1, I have the following:

```
# state.rb
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country, :touch => true

  after_save :count_total_states

  private

  def count_total_states
    total_states = State.where(:country_id => self.country_id).count
    Country.where(:id => self.country_id).update_column(:state, total_states)
  end
end

# states_controller.rb
class StatesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
    @state = @country.states.build(params[:state])
    @state.position = State.where(:country_id => @country.id).maximum(:position).to_i + 1
    @state.save
  end
end
```

When I create a new object for `state`, the following error shows:

```
NoMethodError in StatesController#create

undefined method `update_column' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x1074b0e58>
```

What is the method going back to the controller? Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is because this:

```
Country.where(:id => self.country_id)
```

returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, not a Country. You probably should do one of these two things instead:

```
Country.find(self.country_id).update_column(:state, total_states)
```

or

```
Country.where(:id => self.country_id).first.update_column(:state, total_states)
```

However I would recommend the first option because it does what you really want, finds a record by the ID. Using Where with a primary key is kind of funky, your objective is to return just one exact match and you know its ID so you should just grab it directly.

---

Note: I would also recommend `update_attribute` instead of `update_column`, as `update_column` skips all validation. It's a good idea to validate unless you really can't.

Better yet, the behavior you're using is actually encapsulated into a standard Rails practice called "counter cache". See this [blog post](http://blog.obiefernandez.com/content/2011/08/adding-a-counter-cache-to-existing-records.html) and this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) for a demonstration of a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I should return an object? What do you mean by "not a Country"? Anyway, I can't use `counter cache` because I let user dynamically add/delete states.

Comment: It does return an object - everything in ruby is an object - it just is returning an ActiveRecord::Relation object instead of a Country object. Counter cache works with users dynamically interacting with the page / db -- I use it in my app all the time. Do check out the railscast and blog post, this is also covered in the Code School course Rails Best Practices.

Answer (score 0):

As @Andrew metioned i had to add "first" in order to be able to update my record (using where) properly here is the code snipet just in case

[ruby sinatra]

my view (so you can see these form's values)

```
    ...
    <form action="/device/<%= model.id %>/set-port-value" method="POST">
        <input name="number" type="hidden" value="27"/>
        <input name="value" type="hidden" value="11"/>
        <input type="submit" value="POST" />
    </form>
    ...
```

my controller

```
post '/device/:device_id/set-port-value' do
   # Updating one record:
   Port.where(number: params[:number]).first.update_column(:value, params[:value])

   @models = Port.all
   erb :'port/all'
end
```